# Unique field in user registration form in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, user-registration

I am working in drupal 7. I need a field in the user registration form which needs to be unique. It is an integer field which stores the ID of the user. I have been searching around for a few hours now without any development. Can someone guide me through this?

Thank You.

Comment: Why cant you just use the unique ID for the user that Drupal creates? the UID.  What's the purpose of having a second unique id on a user?

Comment: The unique ID that i need to input is given by the institution for which I am making the website. Its the staff's ID number. So it is already given to each staff. The user registration form needs to ask for their staff ID and I also have to check for their uniqueness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a custom "staff id" field to the user entity type from admin/config/people/account/fields (configuration->people->account settings).  You can add a new integer field, and mark it to display in the registration form, and/or required.

To check that the field value is unqiue you will need to use a custom module. In your custom module use the [form_id_form_alter hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to add a custom validation to the registration form. Then during validation you can check that the value does not already exist in the database and return a form error.

Example of the custom module:

```
<?php
    function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
        $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_user_registration_validate';
    }

    function mymodule_user_registration_validate(&$form,&$form_state){
        $staff_id = $form_state['values']['staff_id_field'];

        $check_unique_query = 'SELECT field_staff_id_value FROM {field_data_staff_id} WHERE field_staff_id_value = :staff_id LIMIT 1';
        //if a result is returned, that means the $staff_id exists
        if (db_query($check_unique_query,array(':staff_id'=>$staff_id))->fetchField()){
            form_set_error('staff_id_field','This Staff ID is already in use');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Unique field module](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field)? Pretty sure it does what you need here.

Comment: I tried this module.. but I could not find the Unique Field option in the user registration configuration. The unique field does appear in content configuration area but NOT in the user registration part. Could you please take a look at it? I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Sorry about my misleading reply earlier, apparently this is [_not_ supported by that module yet](http://drupal.org/node/1094582)

I think your best shot would be using a custom module that does a hook to [user_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7)

Answer (score 0):

Field validation does the trick https://drupal.org/project/field_validation. You can set any rules per field even on the registration form